# Keyboard up arrow not working properly for grouping with typeahead control in ngx-bootstrap (angular7, bootstrap4)

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4, angular7, typeahead, ngx-bootstrap

As per question title, i am using ngx-bootstrap with bootstrap4 in my angular 7 project.

Currently, i have applied grouping feature of typeahed and it will create issue when i use scrolling using keyboard up arrow key.

I have did many tries and many solution but not working.

Also checked valor-soft site for ngx-bootstrap, issue is also exist there.

You can check issue in below link by adding scrolling :
Go to
https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/typeahead
Find for grouping and open stackblitz for typeahead with grouping.

Add below two lines in above stackblitz example inside grouping.html > input tag :

```
[typeaheadScrollable]="true"
[typeaheadOptionsInScrollableView]="5"
```

Comment: The link doesn't work, it directs me to Stackblitz's home page.

Comment: @Myugen, i have updated question, i don't know why it is not working, you can go to main site and then open grouping example for the same.